Hot water issues with Boiler
Hoping to get some insight into an issue we are having. We bought our house a few months ago- it has an older boiler that uses fuel and that has a line that directly heats the hot water tank. We generally have good hot water but when we use too much at once it takes all day for the water to reheat. For example my husband took a shower, then I did, then I did dishes. Part way through doing the dishes I ran out of hot water. This was around 5pm and we didn't regain hot water again until the next morning. I heard the boiler running at various times but no hot water and we are currently not running our heat so I don't know what else it would be doing. Today it happened again- we did 2 loads of laundry with hot water and then no hot water for a shower around 2pm. We had lukewarm water by 6pm and that's it.
We were told by our hvac guys that it is a really good expensive boiler just old and that fuel is not used as much anymore. But they also said we'd never run out of hot water with it directly heating the tank. We do plan to upgrade to gas at some point.
Also want to note that we are currently not using a ton of hot water as we have no kitchen sink so I'm worried once our kitchen is done and we are doing dishes/running the dishwasher more often this will be a regular problem.

There could be a clue here: "I heard the boiler running at various times" The boiler should heat the water rather quickly, surely faster than all night. If the sensors that protect the flaming cycle are seeing wrong circumstances for safe burning, they may be cycling the flame on and off, waiting for the error condition to correct itself. "just old and that fuel is not used as much anymore" = lazy HVAC guys. Oil-fuel furnaces and boilers can last decades and work fine. Try different HVAC techs.

Thanks for the response. I haven’t had them out to look at this issue yet as it happened once last week and then again yesterday so for the most part we have been fine with hot water. They made the comment about the boiler/water tank when they were out servicing it when we first moved in and they also tried to upsell us to a $15000 new system that uses gas. I plan to call them to have them look at this was just hoping to get some ideas especially if they want to try to convince us again to upgrade.

I take it you have a domestic water line that runs directly out of part of the boiler, or do you have a separate taking with boiler water and domestic water piping in it?

Didn't see this question until now, so not sure if it's still relevant or not, or if it's applicable to your specific scenario (since you didn't give a lot of info or pictures on how your setup is configured).  I grew up in a house with a hot water baseboard system with multiple zones of heat to different parts of the house.  If any one or more zones called for heat, the boiler would turn on, the appropriate zone valve(s) would open, the water circulation pump would start, and hot water would start flowing through the appropriate registers (making a lovely pinging sound as the aluminum fins warmed up) until all zones were warmed up to the set temperature.
For domestic hot water, we had a separate hot water tank that was its own zone, with its own temperature sensor and valve and a coil of internal tubing off of the furnace heat plumbing.  If the water in the tank got too cool it would trigger the furnace would turn on, the zone valve would open, and the really hot water directly from the boiler would circulate in the cooler water in the water tank, warming it up.  It worked really well for our needs.
If this is your scenario and everything else in the house is getting well heated, I'd suggest checking to make sure the temperature sensor on your water tank is working and actually calling for heat from the furnace, and that your zone valve is operational for your hot water tank.

If you use up all the hot water, the boiler should run continuously until the water is back up to temperature. It might cycle once when things get close to temperature, but it shouldn't cycle multiple times. If it's cycling multiple times and taking a long time to recover, there's one of two things wrong:

It's installed poorly. There is insufficient flow through the boiler, insufficient storage tank size, or something similar.
It's broken.

Typical system sizing should allow your hot water to recover from depletion in a couple of hours or less. For example, an ordinary electric tank 65 gallon water heater can turn a full tank of 40F cold water into 120F hot water in two hours. You can get usable hot water within an hour, as it rises toward the top of the tank as it's heated. A system that takes more than two hours to recover is poorly installed, poorly sized, or broken.
That said, some older boilers can be difficult to service or difficult to get parts for, making it not that much of a surprise that an HVAC company might try to up-sell you on a newer one. As a rough guide, if your boiler is less than fifteen years old, it should still be within the service lifetime and should be repairable. If it's older than that, you might be into the territory where it becomes less worthwhile to repair.
Also, if it turns out you need to replace the boiler, go 'all of the above' on options to heat hot water. There's tankless gas heaters, heat pump tank water heaters, split heat pump units like the SANCO2, solar hot water heating assisted with tankless or tank heaters, and more. You could see real financial benefits long term from going with a different option than a straight like-for-like replacement of an oil boiler.
And last, be picky about who you work with. If a company hops straight to replacement before even giving you a repair quote, and you don't have a 25+ year old boiler, they are unlikely to be good to work with. It's OK to have more than one company look at the boiler. You might be able to get a free sense of how a given company will be to work with by asking them to quote an upgrade/replacement and seeing what options they give you.
